# How to quit simple Producer-Consumer problem

Tags: c, posix, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

I am trying to work out a simple producer-consumer program. I have this code:

```
//global variable g_lastImage is declared as:
volatile int g_lastImage = 0;

void producer(void) {
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {     
        sem_wait(&g_shm->PSem);
        printf("I:%d\n",i);
        if (i == 5) {
            g_lastImage = 1;
            printf("It's time to say goodbye!\n");
            sem_post(&g_shm->ChSem);
            return;
        }
        printf("producing\n"); 
        i++;
        sem_post(&g_shm->ChSem);
    }
}


void consumer(void) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&g_shm->ChSem);
        if (g_lastImage) {
            printf("Bye!\n");
            return;
        }
        printf("consuming\n");
        sem_post(&g_shm->PSem);
    }
}

int main() {
    alloc(); /*allocates shared memory and two semaphores, 
                  ChSem on initial counter value 0 and PSem on value 1*/
    int processes = 1; //let's start with one process only just for now
    int id = 0, i = 0, status;

    for (i = 0; i < processes; i++) {
        id = fork();
        if (id < 0) {
          perror ("error\n");
          exit(1);
        } else if (id == 0) {
          consumer();
          printf("child exits\n");
          exit(0);
        }
    }
    producer();

    for (i = 0; i < processes; ++i) {
        wait(&status);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Unfortunately this code ends with deadlock. I have this output:

```
I:0
producing
consuming
I:1
producing
consuming
I:2
producing
consuming
I:3
producing
consuming
I:4
producing
consuming
I:5
It's time to say goodbye!
consuming
//deadlock - nothing written
```

Please notice that "Bye!" is not written. On the other hand extra "consuming" is. What is wrong with this solution? Using global variable for detecting the end is not ok? Can't figure it out...

Thank you for any ideas.

**EDIT:**
Acording to your advices I changed the allocation of local variable to volatile and added the '\n' but the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry about that, stupid mistake, this one is printed, though the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to share your flag too, this works as you expect :

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

struct Shared
{
    sem_t PSem ;
    sem_t ChSem ;
    int g_lastImage ;
} * g_shm ;

void producer(void) {
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {     
        sem_wait(&g_shm->PSem);
        printf("I:%d\n",i);
        if (i == 5) {
            g_shm->g_lastImage = 1;
            printf("It's time to say goodbye!\n");
            sem_post(&g_shm->ChSem);
            return;
        }
        printf("producing\n"); 
        i++;
        sem_post(&g_shm->ChSem);
    }
}


void consumer(void) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&g_shm->ChSem);
        if (g_shm->g_lastImage) {
            printf("Bye!\n");
            return;
        }
        printf("consuming\n");
        sem_post(&g_shm->PSem);
    }
}

int main()
{
    g_shm = mmap( NULL , sizeof( struct Shared ) , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS , -1 , 0 );
    sem_init( & g_shm->PSem , 1 , 1 );
    sem_init( & g_shm->ChSem , 1 , 0 );
    g_shm->g_lastImage = 0 ;

    int processes = 1;
    int id = 0, i = 0, status;

    for (i = 0; i < processes; i++)
    {
        id = fork();
        if (id < 0) {
          perror ("error\n");
          exit(1);
        } else if (id == 0) {
          consumer();
          printf("child exits\n");
          exit(0);
        }
    }
    producer();

    for (i = 0; i < processes; ++i)
    {
        wait(&status);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If I could give one hundred pluses I definitely would! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

volatile won't help you here, because you fork your processes. This will result in a copy of g_lastImage and therefore the parentprocess, which calls producer() will change its own value of g_lastImage, whereas the childprocess (who gets its own copy of that variable at fork) will always have g_lastImage == 0 and therefore you end up in a deadlock. You might just insert the allocation of g_lastImage into the allocation of your semaphores as well, as it seems that you allocated them correctly to have them in poth processes ;)

Comment: btw to let it work with more processes I will have to post the ChSem as many times as I have processes right?